# Can Firebase Facebook Authentication be tested in Unity Editor?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm building an Android app that logins with Facebook and authenticates via Firebase Authentication. The app is unity 3d based and the project is set to Android environment.

The app is a simple "Facebook login" button that logs in to Facebook, gets an access token and proceeds to Firebase Authentication to create/login a user.

Only when I've built the APK and ran it on a phone, the user was created. During development a user wasn't created on the Firebase Authentication (using the generated access token from the Facebook SDK).

The code follows the examples both on Facebook and Firebase's docs (and it works on the device).

What am I missing? Does Facebook authentication work only on a device?

Firebase's user, retrieved from the `Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser` has empty values (no email, display name, etc), but no error appears.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour building an iOS app, It might have something to do with the fact that the Editor version of the Facebook Unity sdk. I'm reporting this issue to both the Firebase and the Facebook support teams to see if we can get it resolved. I've also upvoted your question.